# How to use two ngx-toastr observables at the same time?

Tags: javascript, angular

If I use only `onShown` or `onHidden` subscribers it works.

But the problem comes when I want to use both in a single Toast.

```
this.toastr.success("success", "success", {
    positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
    timeOut: 3000,
})
.onShown.subscribe(() => this.toastIsVisible = true)
.onHidden.subscribe(() => this.toastIsVisible = false)
```

I am not sure to understand how to use the [toastr service](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/blob/master/src/lib/toastr/toastr.service.ts)

Any idea how can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could "store" the `toastr` message in a variable and subscribe to the observables on it.

```js
import { ActiveToast, ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  toastrMessage: ActiveToast<any>;

  someFunction() {
    this.toastrMessage = this.toastr.success("success", "success", {
      positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
      timeOut: 3000,
    });

    this.toastrMessage.onShown.subscribe(() => this.toastIsVisible = true)
    this.toastrMessage.onHidden.subscribe(() => this.toastIsVisible = false)  
  }
}
```